# SQL Server UTC to local time

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a function in SQL Server, which returns difference between UTC time and local time of the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using SQL 2008, then using the datetimeoffset type and related functions are much better. But assuming you're talking about the *current* offset, you could do something like:

```
DATEDIFF(minute, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())
```

Comment: You want to use `minute` though, as several time zones are fractional difference from UTC (Mumbai, Nepal etc)